# I want to called id into sibling component in the axios get method and display the output data in vue client table

Tags: vue.js

```
 created () {
   let self = this; 

   // after this point, `self` will reference the Vue instance even in callbacks
  this.$root.$on('eventing', tableDataId => {
    axios.get('http://192.168.2.35:8000/api/v1/post_bi' + '/' + tableDataId)
      .then((response) => {
        // setting `self` to `this` here doesn't make sense because `this`
        // is not refering to the Vue instance in this callback
        self.tableData = response.data;
        console.log(self.tableData)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  })
```

I wrote this code but the output of table data does not show in v client table.

Comment: Why are you accessing root? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to send id(id get from another component ) to axios  method and get data into v-client table , as i am getting data on console but its still not populate on v-client table .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
created () {
   axios.get('http://192.168.2.35:8000/api/v1/post_bi/'+ this.tableDataId)
     .then((response) => {
       this.tableData = response.data;
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.log(error)
   })
})
```

Assuming you have declared tableData and tableDataId in your component like this

```
data() {
  return {
    tableData: '',
    tableDataId: '',
  }
}
```

Comment: here is tableDataId is given from another component in that component i declare this- this.$root.$emit('eventing', tableDataId);     and i want to access  here- this.$root.$once('eventing', tableDataId=> {
        // console.log(tableDataId);
        this.id=tableDataId;
        axios.get('http://192.168.2.35:8000/api/v1/post_bi/'+this.id)
          .then((response) => {
            this.tableData = response.data;
          })
         
          })  tableData display on console log but not view in table format.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

Comment: I am using this in first component 
this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$root.$emit('eventing', tableDataId);
          })

and
 this in another component
this.$root.$once('eventing', tableDataId=> {
        // console.log(tableDataId);
        this.id = tableDataId;
})